# Load ruenner Ajax true client protocol script recording issue

Tags: loadrunner

We are working on the Load runner Ajax true client protocol scripting. The given flow is when we double click on a record , it will navigate to the new window. But while recording the script new window is not opening.

- Loadrunner version – 12.55
- Internet explorer version - 11

Application supports only IE browser.

How can I resolve the recording issue?

Comment: Just to clarify. In the page, you have some records displayed. When you click one of the records in the real world it will open a new IE window but in TruClient it does nothing?

Comment: Hi , Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

In TruClient opening a new window is translated into opening a new tab in the TruClient browser. This should not affect your work.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Once Open the new window, I need to perform other actions\transactions on that window.

Regards,
Srini

Comment: You can do all the operations in the new tab. It is the same thing.